# i want to display data from two tables

Tags: php, sql

I am using this code and working fine

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d_bonus ORDER BY  date DESC"); 
?>
<table border='1' align=center>
<tr>
<th class="auto-style2" style="height: 25">USER</th>
<th class="auto-style2" style="height: 25">AMOUNT</th>
<th class="auto-style2" style="height: 25">DATE</th>
</tr>


<?php 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
      {
echo "<tr> ";
     echo "<td>" .$row[userid] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[b_amount] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[date] . "</td>";
     }
echo "</tr> " ;
      ?>

</table>
```

I want to display username instead of userid ..

username will be taken from different table using the userid.

how can i display username in place of userid..

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: Can you please provide DDLs for the two tables?

Comment: Oh dear...as a heads up, I highly recommend not using PHP's mysql_* functions; they've been deprecated for a bit, and can be removed from future PHP versions at any time. [Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have `username` in `user` table try to replace your query with this

```
SELECT d_bonus.*, user.username FROM d_bonus INNER JOIN user ON d_bonus.userid=user.userid order by d_bonus.date DESC;
```

and change `$row[userid]` to `$row[username]`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query with something like

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM d_bonus INNER JOIN users ON userid=users.id ORDER BY  date DESC");
```